# Замена в строке при первом совпадении

Tags: php

Есть строка, например `“site.com/categori/categori-artickle-1”`.

Нужно поменять в этой строке первое вхождение `“categori”`, на `“categories”`. Пробовал через `str_replace`, но в таком случае меняется и второе вхождение ключа в строку. Как можно указать? В данном случае, конечно, для поиска можно указать, например `“categori/”` , но не всегда это можно сделать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252705/10138734

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Str\_replace можно ли каким то образом заменить только первое вхождение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274914/str-replace-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 3):

```
$textbody = "site.com/categori/categori-artickle-1";
$textbody = preg_replace("~categori~", "categories", $textbody, 1);
echo $textbody;
```